# How to dynamically remove rows from the bottom going upwards

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a column in Power Query

```
[Column1]
X
null  
null
null
null
Y
null
null
null
```

in which I want to eliminate the bottom going up to "y" in this example,
leaving only the top portion.

```
[Column1]
X
null  
null
null
null
```

I could do this by eliminating a specific number of rows, but I'd rather do it dynamically so that, no matter how long the data below Y gets, it will still cut off above Y, leaving only X and the data below X

I know that Table.Skip can do the same thing from the top going down, but this is more like a reverse of that process.

Answer (score 2):

In Home ... Advanced Editor ... try using this, replacing Source with your prior step name

```
= Table.FirstN(Source, each [Column1]<>"Y")
```

Comment: This is perfect.